# OWL Ontology: Represent increasing number, like first, second, third

Tags: ontology, owl

I have a question about an **OWL ontology** that I am making. I have a class that is actually an ID class and I would like to have instances: ***first, second, third*** etc.

The *first solution* that I have figured is creating individuals {first, second, third etc} for this class, but then I have to write a huge number of individuals.

The *other solution* is to create a data property that will be connected with my class that has type "integer".

The second solution looks more appropriate but the thing is that I can't represent the word "first", just the number 1.

Do you know how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class of ordinals that are uniquely identified by an integer, like so (in [Turtle](http://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/) syntax):

```
:hasPosition  a  owl:DatatypeProperty, owl:FunctionalProperty ;
    rdfs:range  xsd:integer .
:Ordinal  a  owl:Class ;
    rdfs:subClassOf  [
        a  owl:Restriction ;
        owl:onProperty  :hasPosition ;
        owl:someValuesFrom  :integer
    ] ;
    owl:hasKey ( :hasPosition ) .
```

Note the use of `owl:hasKey` (introduced in [OWL 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-overview/)) which means that the value of `:hasPosition` identifies a unique instance. The property is functional so that an instance cannot have two distinct positions.